# Java Callback-like/event method?

Tags: java, android, events

I might be on the wrong track here, and should be thinking events/publish-subscriber, if so, please enlighten me.

I have an android project running, where I have a layout which acts as an on-screen menu. Implemented in several activities/"parent-views" with the use of '< include>'. Working nicely.

Now, some of the functionality is general and global. Like I have an "add"-button, which does something, that it should always do. Then I'd like the possibility to customize what it does in addition to this, based on the activity where the action originated.

I have seperated menulogic in a simple java class, with the constructor taking an activity as a parameter. From here, I can attach clicklisteners to the buttons in the menu fine, and do stuff on click.

What I'd like is something like:

```
private void addBtn(String text, String path) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.dynamicButtonLayout);
        Button newButton = new Button(parentActivity);
        newButton.setText(text);
        newButton.setTag(path);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    //Do Stuff.
                    fireDoneHandlingButtonClick();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And then have a way of handling this method in the parent activity. Should I be thinking of events, or should I be thinking of a way to add a method as an argument to the addBtn method from the activity, which can be fired from inside the click-listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [How To Implement Your Own Listener in Android](http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/) or [Fire and Forget Messages (events) in Android](http://www.mikenimer.com/?p=671)